# how SageMaker to access s3 bucket data

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I was using the code `pd.read_json('s3://example2020/kaggle.json')` to access S3 bucket data, but it threw the error of `FileNotFoundError: example2020/kaggle.json`.

The methods I tried:

**[Region]**
The s3 bucket is in Ohio region while the SageMaker notebook instance is in Singapore. Not sure if this matters. I tried to recreate a s3 bucket in Singapore region but I still cannot access it and got the same file not found error.

**[IAM Role]**
I checked the permission of IAM-SageMaker Execution role
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is still IAM permission.

I created a new notebook instance and a new IAM role. You would be asked how to access s3 bucket. I chose `all s3 bucket`. Then the problem solved. 
[image]

**[Solution]**
In Resource tab, check whether bucket name is general.
 [image]

If you changed old IAM and it is not working, you can create a new IAM role. And attach this role to the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

While providing access to all of S3 for an IAM role solves your immediate access problem, it's not best practice, as it could lead to security vulnerabilities down the road.

A better solution would be to provide that role with a policy specific to the bucket it needs to work in. For your example, you'd add this inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example2020",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example2020/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```